# Child form always in front of parent in Win Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple multi form application, which looks like this :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Parent Form";
        var childForm = new ChildForm2() { Owner = this };
        childForm.Show();
    }
}
public class ChildForm2 : Form
{
    public ChildForm2()
    {
        this.Text = "Child Form";
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

In this scenario, the child form is always in front of parent form. When I click the parent form, the child stays in the foreground.

This can be solved by not setting `Owner = this` and the app will behave exactle as I want it to, but this introduces a new issue. I control this program via another another C# program using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. In it, I call `Process.CloseMainWindow`, which allows the child process to fire `Form.OnClose` event and close gracefully. If I don't set the child owner, the parent process will just close the child form and not the whole applicaiton. I did not find other way to close the main window.

How to fix this ? I want to be able to have the main window in the foreground while still being able to close the whole app with the `Process.CloseMainWindow`.

Comment: Process.MainWindowHandle is pretty troublesome, the OS has no way to explicitly state "this is my main window".  It uses a heuristic, it assumes that the first window that got created is the main one.  And yes, in this code it is ChildWindow2 whose native window gets created, before Form1's.  Very simple to fix, instead of assigning Owner explicitly use `childForm.Show(this);`.  Moving the code to the Load event is another way to fix it.

Comment: ... or move `childForm.Show(this);` to the `Form1.Shown()` handler. If you decide to use UI Automation to automate the application, the `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent` is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have to code this explicitly in your application. You have to implement that the application closes all windows if the main window is supposed to close. If you have non-modal windows (which you apparently want) you have to explicitly close these when the main window closes to close the application properly. Note that if the child window is modal, you normally cannot close the main window before closing the child window - this is intended UI behavior.

Of course, you can always kill (forcibly terminate) the application, but that would likely cause loss of data or have other undesired effects.